# Struts 2 internationalization not work in Intellij IDEA

Tags: jakarta-ee, internationalization, struts

I am learning Struts 2 internationalization and locale.

The page always display `login.user`, `login.password` and `login.submit` in browser.

I want to display texts are English or Simplified Chinese like that `User`, `Password`,`Login` not a `login.user` etc.

**index.jsp**

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Internationalization</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%--user select language page--%>
        <s:url var="loginCN" action="changeLocale" namespace="/">
            <s:param name="language">cn</s:param>
        </s:url>
        <s:url var="loginEN" action="changeLocale" namespace="/">
            <s:param name="language">en</s:param>
        </s:url>
        <a href="<s:property value="#loginCN" />">简体中文</a>
        <a href="<s:property value="#loginEN" /> ">English</a>

    <%--input form data--%>
        <form action="login" method="post">
            <s:text name="login.user" />
            <input type="text" name="username"/><br/>
            <s:text name="login.password" />
            <input type="text" name="password" /><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="<s:text name="login.submit" />" />
            <!--output validation information-->
            <p><s:fielderror fieldName="username" /></p>
        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

**struts.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="viewResources.global" />

    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

        <action name="changeLocale" class="web.struts.action.ChangeLocaleAction">
            <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

#### global.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    <entry key="global.success">Success</entry>
    <entry key="login.password">Password</entry>
    <entry key="login.submit">Login</entry>
    <entry key="login.user">User</entry>
</properties>
```

#### global_en_US.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    <entry key="global.success">Success</entry>
    <entry key="login.password">Password</entry>
    <entry key="login.submit">Login</entry>
    <entry key="login.user">User</entry>
</properties>
```

#### global_zh_CN.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    <entry key="global.success">成功</entry>
    <entry key="login.password">密码</entry>
    <entry key="login.submit">登录</entry>
    <entry key="login.user">用户</entry>
</properties>
```

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phw6L.png)

[Run Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEeot.png)

Comment: Where are your I18N property files? What's in them?

Comment: The files at src-->viewResources-->Resource Bundle 'global'.  I will add more details about it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: When I create Resource Bundle, I select a checkbox that "Use XML-based properties files". So we will see global_en_US.xml, not global_en_US.properties.

Comment: Is that where they're supposed to be? In the past they always went in/sec/resources but maybe it's different now.

Comment: Yes, I do not know this Resource Bundle should be put it into somewhere. I search for the Internet, most example in Eclipse, not IDEA. I only find a web page that put it into src/. I doubt that the application does not load resource bundle. No matter how made me confused, thanks your reply.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have solved the problem.

Firstly, the bug depends on "global.xml", "global_zh_CN.xml" and "global_en_US.xml" files.

Secondly, the Resource Bundle files` location is error.

I use the global internationalization resources, the related files(xxx.properties) should be put into src such as src/xxx.properties.

The most significant thing is ".xml". When I create Resource Bundle in IntelliJ IDEA, we should not select the checkbox "Use XML-based properties files". This is the key to solve the problem.